# Redirect subdirectory to root

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect some subdirectory into the root, i.e.,

> https://example.com/sub/* --[redirect]--> https://example.com/*

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: For example: `rewrite ^/sub(.*)$ $1 redirect;`

Comment: But that doesn't redirect me, isn't it? It displays the same page but the URL stays intact

Comment: See [the manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) - but **redirect** means Nginx issues a 302 redirect.